# How to add download image or Pdf/any doc in filepond?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, filepond

How to add download image or Pdf/any doc in filepond. I am using Filepond with vue framework. i also need a big preview of image when i click on image thumbnail how to achieve this with filepond?

```
<file-pond
            ref="pond"
            class-name="my-pond"
            label-idle="Drop files here..."
            :allow-multiple="allowMultiple"
            accepted-file-types="image/jpeg, image/png, application/pdf,"
            :files="myFiles"
            v-on:init="handleFilePondInit"
            @addfile="onaddfile"
            @removefile="onRemoveFile"
        >
        </file-pond>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This third party plugin adds a download button https://github.com/nielsboogaard/filepond-plugin-get-file

You can use `@activatefile` to run logic when the user clicks a file item.
https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/filepond-instance/#callbacks